# Uploading images inside array not working

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I want to upload multiple images. `img[]` contains all the image files to be uploaded.The values are successfully inserted into database imploded with `commas(,)` .But the images are not uploaded to the specified folder named `photos` .

```
<input type="file" name="img[]" id="img[]" />


$n=$_FILES["img"]["name"];
$t=$_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
$image=implode(",",$n);


             $ex=explode(",",$image);
         $i=0;
         foreach($ex as $item)
         {

             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img[$i]"]["tmp_name"],"photos/$ex[$i]");

             $i++;
         }
```

Comment: Sorry man, but your code is bad. Multiply file-uploading isn't "5-min to do thing". What if someone would upload php script with `<?php phpinfo()`, you probably do not expect that. You need to write a class which would deal with file validation (including size and extension)

Comment: And also, `move_uploaded_file()` returns `TRUE` on success, `FALSE` on failure. Nowhere in your code you check that - so that you have no idea whether they have been uploaded or not

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump($_FILES)` to see what structure this array have? Because it should be multidimension array when you upload many files. Read this http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your correct code should be

```
<input type="file" name="img[]" id="img[]" />


$n=$_FILES["img"]["name"];
$t=$_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"];
$image=implode(",",$n);

 // no need to explode here

     foreach($n as $key=>$item)
     {
         //name will be there in $items 
        // use temp_name of same file for which you are using name using $_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$key]
         move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"][$key],"photos/$item");
     }
```